# How to get closing message from IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, idapro-sdk

Is there any way to get  SDK API  message when Ida Pro is closing?
I write plug-in that connect with other  application and I need to close connections when IDA is closing.

Comment: If this were OS-specific you could use some mechanism like window hooks on Windows, but I can see how an IDA API may be the better choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way to solve the problem with getting close message is create `term(self)` method in the UIHook class but not in plugin class.
The benefit of this way that is it usable with ida pro scripts not just plugins.
Example:
https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/idapython/blob/master/examples/ex_uihook.py

Answer (score 2):

Your plugin class can implement the `term(self)` method, which will be called when IDA unloads the plugin. Unloading a plugin might happen at different occasions depending on the value returned by your `init(self)` method when the plugin was loaded.

You should note the plugin may be loaded and unloaded several times during the execution of a single IDA instance, though. For example a plugin may be loaded once when IDA first starts without a loaded binary, and then be unloaded and reloaded when a binary is loaded (either an IDB or a binary loaded and analyzed for the first time).